# Getting web service response in SOAP on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, soap, web

I have set up a web service with an .asmx file and its web methods are being called via Ajax (all using asp.net scriptmanager etc) on the clientside.

When I call the webservice and look at the value of the return value in the callback, it is never in the 'SOAP' format, ie in xml. instead the value is returned in its raw form.
So for instance if I return a string from the webservice, the result passed to my successful callback is the string, not encoded or surrounded by XML tags.
How can I change this so I can see it in the SOAP format?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling from jquery? possible return in Json format. My guess without seeing your code.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are being returned the result of the web service function and letting .NET handle all of the underlying SOAP details. What you need to do if you want to see the HTTP SOAP response in your code, is instead of referencing the Web Service and invoking the function, issue an HTTP SOAP request. In VB.NET:

```
Dim _soapRequest As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
                                "<soap:Body>" & _
                                "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">" & _
                                "<Celsius>" & 100 & "</Celsius>" & _
                                 "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>" & _
                                "</soap:Body>" & _
                                "</soap:Envelope>"
Dim response As String = DoRequestResponse(_soapRequest, "http://localhost:88/Service1.asmx")
```

and the DoRequestResponse Function looks like this

```
Public Function DoRequestResponse(ByVal _p_RequestString As String, ByVal _p_RequestURL As String) As String

    Dim _httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim _httpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
    Dim _streamReq As Stream
    Dim _streamResp As Stream
    Dim _streamReader As StreamReader
    Dim _responseString As String
    Dim _bytesToWrite() As Byte

    Try
        _httpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(_p_RequestURL), HttpWebRequest)
        _httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        _httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
        _httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000
        Dim EncodingType As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        _bytesToWrite = EncodingType.GetBytes(_p_RequestString)

        _streamReq = _httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
        _streamReq.Write(_bytesToWrite, 0, _bytesToWrite.Length)
        _streamReq.Close()

        _httpWebResponse = DirectCast(_httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        _streamResp = _httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()

        _streamReader = New StreamReader(_streamResp)
        _responseString = _streamReader.ReadToEnd()

        _streamReader.Close()
        _httpWebResponse.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim _ex As WebException = ex
        Console.Write(_ex.Status)
        Console.Write(DirectCast(_ex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
        Throw New Exception("DoRequestResponse Error :" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return _responseString

End Function
```

You can do something like this in your code-behind of the asp.net page, and call it from AJAX, via postback, etc., which will then post to your .asmx web service and return the SOAP response.

Comment: -1: He's using Ajax, and one should never create XML by string manipulation.

Comment: he could use Ajax to invoke a server side function that Posts to the web service in order to retrieve the SOAP envelope. I agree about string manipulation, but it's an example and is common in other languages like PHP, so that's really just your opinion.

Comment: My opinion happens to be correct. Building XML through string manipulation will very often result in bogus XML, whereas .NET (perhaps unlike PHP) has a robust and easy mechanism for producing valid and correct XML.